# Why isnt possible update to TOR 8.5.1 in Tails 3.14 on usb?

Tags: tails, browsers, update

I can't update the new TOR in TAILS!
Persistent volume and administrator are active.
Thank you.

Comment: as far as i know, you are supposed to update Tails as a whole... - as soon as there is no Tails 3.14.1, i guess TorBrowser 8.5.1 is not a security related bugfix.